# How to get the current time using Event Channel?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I need to get current time using Event Channel.Receive on button click. I don't understand how to write code in kotlin file. How can I get the current time using Event Channel? The date needs to be received only through the Event Channel.
I have attached the Flutter code and kotlin file below.

```js
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const EventChannel _eventPlatform =
      EventChannel('samples.flutter.dev/eventChannel_profile');
  static Stream<int> get getCurrentTime {
    return _eventPlatform.receiveBroadcastStream().cast();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body:  Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    StreamBuilder<int>(
                      stream: getCurrentTime,
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Text("Current Time: ${snapshot.data}");
                        } else {
                          return const Text("Waiting for get data...");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Get Update Profile'),
                      onPressed: _getUpdateProfile,
                    ),
                  ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

My Kotlin:

```js
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val EVENT_CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/profile"
    private lateinit var channel: EventChannel
    var eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null
    
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
 
        channel = EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, EVENT_CHANNEL)
        channel.setStreamHandler(
            object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
                override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {

                    }
                }
                override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
                    Log.w("Android", "EventChannel onCancel called")
                }
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here. If it is really the current time you need, there are better ways to do so using pure Dart:

```dart
DateTime current = DateTime.now();
Stream timer = Stream.periodic( Duration(seconds: 1), (i){
       current = current.add(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return current;
    });

timer.listen((data)=> print(data));
```

However if this is just a learning exercise on communicating with the native platform, the [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-obj-c-tab) has a very detailed guide on how to do so including code samples in Kotlin.

Another great resource (discussing event channels specifically) would be the [A In-Depth Dive into Streaming Across Platform Channels on Flutter](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20518849-an-in-depth-dive-into-streaming-data-across-platform-channels-on-flutter).

Comment: Thanks for your reply) I need to get date using Event Channel.